# Select count giving zero rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

***The table have 11 rows***
**Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `zars_all` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9,9
```

**Result**

Zero Rows, even there are two rows having id 10 and 11

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM `zars_all` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9,9
```

**Result**

Two Rows having id 10 and 11

I have tried using column names as value in Count but it does't help. Any help is appreciated and please tell me if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)` returns **ONE** row - the number of records counted

Comment: but this time it is giving zero rows I don't know why

Comment: You offset by 9. When there is only one record and you want to skip the first 9 records - what should the DB show you other than nothing?

Comment: It means starting from 9 give me 9 results.

Comment: Yes it means skip the first 9 records and give me the next 9. But you have only 1 record with `COUNT()`

Comment: Just leave the `limit` part and run the queries without it and you will see

Comment: but I want to run the limit part so that I can see how many records are there after 9 records
In this query I want to skip 9 latest records and after them showing the number of records left

Comment: well then use `select count(*) - 9 FROM zars_all` and you are done.

Comment: it says -8 but it should return 2

Comment: Run the query of my comment above - just that one without adding anything. It returns 2 if there are 11 records.

Comment: It worked . The pagination is working tooo THANK YOU GUYSSSS

Comment: If you display paginated data then just handle the display of the count of records on the current page in your PHP code. There you iterate over the resultset anyway. It is hard so tell what you are after without seeing a specific line of code you are stuck with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first sentence `SELECT COUNT(*)` returns an integer.

That means that the trailing `LIMIT 9,9` is setting a minimum of 9 elements and a maximum of 9 elements.

Let’s examine the `LIMIT offset, count` clause parameters:

> The **offset** specifies the offset of the first row to return.
>   The **count** specifies the maximum number of rows to return.

Your offset is out of bounds, that is why you get **no rows**.

Please remove that and leave it like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `zars_all` ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Also there is no need to order

Answer (score 1):

Waqas,
`LIMIT` cannot be applied directly along with `COUNT` instead change your query like

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (select * from zars_all limit 9,9) as a"**;
```